# VBA - How do I create a namespace for the root of the drive?

Tags: vba

How do I create a namespace which represents the root of a drive? For example, I want to `ParseName` a filename that is in the root of C

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\\")
Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName("foo.jpg")
```

objFolder is set to null / nothing

Comment: Are you able to get it to work when the file is in a sub-folder?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the two backslashes and go with objShell.NameSpace("C:")?

Comment: @SilentD Yes I have to no avail

Comment: What about:  Dim sFolder as string  sFolder = "C:\"  and then Set objFolder = obShell.Namespace((sFolder))  Notice the doubled up parenthesis.

Comment: Just one \ like: `ObjShell.Namespace("C:\") works (tested it). Did you try that?

Comment: Double brackets worked! @SilentD if you make an answer and explain why, I'll accept! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a post several pages into a Google search from Dirk Goldgar, MS Access MVP from 2005.  He reported the following which contained the answer:

> I'm not an expert in this area, but I suspect that the string
>   *variable* is passed differently than the string literal -- and there can be no implicit conversion because you're using late binding. You
>   can force evaluation of the string variable and pass the result of
>   that evaluation to the NameSpace method by wrapping the variable name
>   in an extra set of parentheses, like this:
>
> Set myFolder = myApp.NameSpace((strTemp))

I never knew about the double parentheses, either. I would have figured it was a copy/paste or formatting issue.

Comment: You have strong Google-Fu.  +1